# SAT Algebra and elementary number theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question 1. If $a>5$ and $b>4$, then which of the following must be true?

i. $a>b$

ii. $a+b>9$

iii.$a+b>11$

I think all 3 are true, but the answer is ii. only.

Question 2. $|s-5|=8$ and $|t+2|=10$. Which of the following values is a possible value of $s+t$? Answer: 1.

a. $-4$

b. $-3$

c. $1$

d. $13$

e. $25$

I could not solve with systems of equations or any method.

Comment: In question 1, $a$ could be $6$ and $b$ could be $1000$, right? Then (i) is not true. Something that might help make this kind of question clearer is to reformulate it about money instead of about abstract numbers.   Suppose you know that Alice has more than \$5 and Bob has more than \$4. Do you know that Alice has more than Bob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is not necessarily larger than $B$ because $A$ could be $5.1$ and $B$ could be $5.2$ (this is just one case of the infinite number of cases where $B$ is larger than $A$). Using these values for $A$ and $B$ we also notice that the sum of $A$ and $B$ doesn't have to be larger than $11$.

As for your second question, we know that $s-5 = 8$ or $s-5 = -8$ and that $t+2 = 10$ or $t+2 =-10$ so $s = 13$ or $s=-3$ and $t = 8$ or $t=-12$. Checking all possible sums of $s$ and $t$ we find that $1$ is the only sum that is one of the answer choices (occurs when $s = 13$ and $t = -12$).

Answer (score 0):

In the first question, (I) may not be true (counterexample: $a=6$ and $b=7$). (II) is true, by adding the two inequalities. (III) may not be true (counterexample: $a=6$ and $b=5$).

For the second question, $|s-5|=8$ implies that $s$ is $-3$ or $13$ (because the distance from $s$ to $5$ is $8$, imagine a number line if it helps; alternatively, you could solve for $s-5= \pm 8$). Similarly, $t$ must be $8$ or $-12$. So there are $4$ possible values of $s+t$, you just have to check them all.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Given: $a > 5$ and $b > 4$}$$

> i. $a>b$

FALSE. For example $a=6$ and $b=10$ is a counter-example.

> ii. $a+b>9$

TRUE. This follows immediately from $a>5$ and $b>4$.

> iii. $a+b>11$

FALSE. For example, $a=6$ and $b=5$ is a counter-example.

> Question $2$. $|s-5|=8$ and $|t+2|=10$. What are the possible values of $s+t$.

$|s-5|=8 \implies s \in \{-3, 13\}$

$|t+2|=10$ \implies $t \in \{-12, 8\}$

So $s+t \in \{-15, 5, 1, 21   \}$